# Unable to enter text in Compose new Tweet box on Twitter using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, twitter

I'm trying to automate Tweeting using Selenium Webdriver in Chrome. I can login and click the Tweet button, opening the Compose new Tweet box, but when I try to enter text with `element.sendKeys(tweetMessage);` I get

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not
>   interactable

Using:
selenium-java-3.141.59
chrome=74.0.3729.169
(Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6)

Here's the relevant code:

```
    String composeTweetXpath = "//div[@aria-labelledby='Tweetstorm-tweet-box-0-label Tweetstorm-tweet-box-0-text-label']//div";
    String tweetMessage = "This is my test Tweet";

    WebDriver driver;
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
.
.
.
.

try {
    element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(composeTweetXpath)));
    System.out.println("After wait until...");
    element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(composeTweetXpath));
    System.out.println("After driver.findElement...");
    element.click();
    System.out.println("After element.click...");
    element.sendKeys(tweetMessage);
    System.out.println("Found Tweet box and typed message");
} catch ( Exception e1) {
    System.out.println("Failed to find Tweet box");
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'm surprised that I don't get the error on `element.click();` but on element.sendKeys(tweetMessage); My output from this snippet is :

After wait until...

After driver.findElement...

After element.click...

Moved to element...

Failed to find Tweet box

org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable

I've also tried using:

```
    String js = "arguments[1].value = arguments[0]; ";   
    System.out.println("Executing : " + js);
    javascript.executeScript(js, tweetMessage, element);
```

...instead of `element.sendKeys(tweetMessage);` This doesn't fall into the } catch ( Exception e1) { block, but still doesn't enter the text in the Compose new Tweet box.

Strangely enough, if I use `driver = new FirefoxDriver();` I get the TimeoutException error at this line:

```
    element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(composeTweetXpath)));
```

> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed:
>   waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath:
>   //div[@aria-labelledby='Tweetstorm-tweet-box-0-label
>   Tweetstorm-tweet-box-0-text-label']//div (tried for 10 second(s) with
>   500 milliseconds interval)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CSS selector

ChromeDriver newDriver = new ChromeDriver();
        WebDriverWait waits = new WebDriverWait(newDriver, 50);

```
    newDriver.get("https://twitter.com/");
    newDriver.findElement(By.name("session[username_or_email]")).sendKeys("arungnairktm@gmail.com");
    newDriver.findElement(By.name("session[password]")).sendKeys("Cisco_12345678");
    newDriver.findElement(By.className("submit")).click();
    WebElement composes = waits
            .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("global-new-tweet-button")));
    composes.click();
    WebElement tweets = waits.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(newDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector(
            "#Tweetstorm-tweet-box-0 > div.tweet-box-content > div.tweet-content > div.RichEditor.RichEditor--emojiPicker.is-fakeFocus > div.RichEditor-container.u-borderRadiusInherit > div.RichEditor-scrollContainer.u-borderRadiusInherit > div.tweet-box.rich-editor.is-showPlaceholder"))));

    tweets.click();
    tweets.sendKeys("heys");
```